# How to fill color within cv2.ellipse figure?

Tags: python, opencv

I have this code. Which takes image and draws ellipse over the defined point.Like this [sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jK5iJ.png). But i am struggling to figure out how can i fill color in it?

```
def annotate_image(annotations, i):
   file_name = annotations[i][0]
   PATH= "/content/content/train/Class1_def/"+file_name+'.png'
   img=cv2.imread(PATH)
   #print(img.shape)
   img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
   semi_major= int(float(annotations[i][1]))
   semi_minor= int(float(annotations[i][2]))
   rotation= int(float(annotations[i][3]))
   x_pos_ellip= int(float(annotations[i][4]))
   y_pos_ellip= int(float(annotations[i][5]))
   center_coordinates= (x_pos_ellip, y_pos_ellip)
   axesLength= (semi_major,semi_minor)
   angle= int(float(rotation))
   startAngle = 0
   endAngle = 360
   # Red color 
   color = (255, 0, 0)  
   # Line thickness 
   thickness = 2    
   cv2.ellipse(img, center_coordinates, axesLength, 
       angle, startAngle, endAngle, color, thickness) 

   return img
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a negative value for the thickness parameter. From the [docs on `cv.ellipse()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga28b2267d35786f5f890ca167236cbc69):

> **thickness** Thickness of the ellipse arc outline, if positive. Otherwise, this indicates that a filled ellipse sector is to be drawn.

This is true of all of OpenCV's drawing functions for closed shapes. If you want both a fill and a separate stroke, simply draw the filled ellipse first, then the stroke on top.

Answer (score 3):

Set `thickness =  -1`, this will fill the color in it.